# Installing and using Mink with Browserkit driver

Tags: composer-php, silex, mink

I seem to be unable to install Mink with Browserkit driver on Centos. 
I am using these instructions: https://github.com/minkphp/MinkBrowserKitDriver

The steps I am taking is by:

1. adding a file in my project directory with the name composer.json and the contents:

   {
       "require": {
           "behat/mink":                   "~1.5",
           "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "~1.1"
       }
   }
2. Use the commands as below.

> $> curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
>
> $> php composer.phar install

3. Now there are 3 files (composer.json, composer.lock, composer.phar) and one folder (vendor) in the project directory. Where do I run the "Usage example" code from (as on the documentation)?

I have tried adding require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; to my test.php file:

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use Behat\Mink\Mink,
    Behat\Mink\Session,
    Behat\Mink\Driver\BrowserKitDriver;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client;

$app  = require_once(__DIR__.'/app.php'); // Silex app

$mink = new Mink(array(
    'silex' => new Session(new BrowserKitDriver(new Client($app))),
));

$mink->getSession('silex')->getPage()->findLink('Chat')->click();
```

but getting a fatal error that app.php cannot be opened. I have also tried adding the following to test.php:

```
require_once 'vendor/behat/mink-browserkit-driver/tests/app.php';
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: the error is just telling you that the file app.php in the current directory cannot be opened. Do you have the test.php and app.php in the same directory? Can you double check the name of the file?

Comment: Where should test.php (with the specified code) be located? Currently app.php is in project_directory/vendor/behat/mink-browserkit-driver/tests/app.php (as automatically assigned with the installation process, described), and test.php is in the project_directory. Or from scratch, how would I get Mink working with Browserkit driver? The instructions seem quite vague. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Its seems you're missing some guideline in order to organize your code. Before integrating Behat and Mink, first of all you should organize your Silex project. My advice is for you to take a look at the official [Silex Skeleton project](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton).

After that you can start by installing behat, mink and your driver:

```
cd path/to/your/silex/project/root
composer require behat/behat:~2.5 behat/mink behat/mink-browserkit-driver
```

Then you can [initialize behat](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/quick_intro.html#basic-usage).

```
bin/behat --init
```

Then configure your mink driver in *behat.yml* (on your project root directory)

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      browserkit: ~
      base_url: http://my.dev.host
```

*Notice that browser kit cannot execute JS, remember that (if you want to execute JS on your tests, you should [install another driver](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/guides/drivers.html))*

After that you can start writing your features on the features directory (behat should've created that for you), for example if you have this controller in *src/controllers.php*:

```
<?php
//...
$app->get('/hello', function () use ($app) {
  return new Response("Hello world!");
});
```

You can write the feature (on features/greeting.feature):

```
Feature: Greetings from /hello page
  In order to say hello world
  As a visitor
  I need to go to the /hello page and see Hello world!

  Scenario: See Hello world!
    Given I am on "/hello"
    Then I should see "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use full behat extension for silex: https://github.com/tabbi89/Behat-Silex-Extension

You can check how integrations of Mink and browserKit work there.